# Exporting Console Output of Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, pipeline

I have built a pipeline which runs a set of sql scripts to generate results. I would like to be able to export the console output, ideally into a .txt file or .xlsx file. Is this possible? For info I drive the pipeline via GitHub.

Thanks

Tried searching the web but have been unable to find a solution

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to Save the Console output to a file and then Commit it to Github? Check the following sample Pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Sample') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Somehitng 1"
                    echo "Something 2"
                    // Read the console log
                    def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text
                    //Write the log to a file
                    writeFile(file: "Log_${BUILD_NUMBER}.txt", text: consoleLog, encoding: "UTF-8")
                    sh'''
                        git add *
                        git commit -m "Add console log"
                        git push
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi yes, ideally would save as a .txt file and then be saved in a workplace, do you know if it is possible to save an output file to a local directory?

Comment: @DanT96 that's what I'm doing in the above code. If you check the `writeFile` line, here I'm writing a file to the local file system.

Comment: Thanks, so would I need to change anything in the above script when adding it to my JenkinsFile in github?

Comment: @DanT96 you can remove the `sh` block if that's not needed.